# Printer CreateDC/CreateIC fails on Windows 10 with RDP printers

Tags: winapi, printing, windows-10

## Short Version

When calling **CreateDC**/**CreateIC** with a redirected (i.e. remote desktop) printer, the calls fails (i.e. returns `0`):

```
printerDC := CreateDC(nil, 'EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)', nil, nil);
```

## Long Version

I am trying to call **[CreateDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createica)**/**[CreateIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdca)** for a printer that happens to be redirected by Remote Desktop Client:

```
printerDC := CreateDC(nil, 'EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)', nil, nil);
```

The code works in Windows 7, but fails in Windows 10 - returning `NULL` (*i.e.* `zero`)

I really am using a real printer (i.e. not a virtual *print to file*, *Print to PDF* virtual printer):

[image: Screenshot of debugger inspecting printer name variable at runtime]

But the same also fails for my other redirected remote printers; some "real" some "virtual":

```
CreateIC(…, 'Fax',                                          …) ⇒ 0xBF21704F
CreateIC(…, 'Xerox Phaser 6500N',                           …) ⇒ 0x85214A3E
CreateIC(…, 'Microsoft Print to PDF',                       …) ⇒ 0x76213A00
CreateIC(…, 'OneNote for Windows 10',                       …) ⇒ 0x162149B2
CreateIC(…, 'Brother MFC-7840W Printer',                    …) ⇒ 0xF62139F2
CreateIC(…, 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer',                …) ⇒ 0x6B214609
CreateIC(…, 'Send To OneNote 2010',                         …) ⇒ 0
CreateIC(…, 'Fax (redirected 2)',                           …) ⇒ 0
CreateIC(…, 'OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)',        …) ⇒ 0
CreateIC(…, 'Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)',       …) ⇒ 0
CreateIC(…, 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)', …) ⇒ 0
CreateIC(…, 'Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)',        …) ⇒ 0
CreateIC(…, 'EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)',          …) ⇒ 0
```

But the call doesn't fail for "local" printers:

```
                                     ┊
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Printer name                       ┊           ║ Returned DC ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Fax                                ┊           ║ 0xBF21704F  ║
║ Fax (redirected 2)                 ┊           ║ 0           ║ 
║ Xerox Phaser 6500N                 ┊           ║ 0x85214A3E  ║
║ Send To OneNote 2010               ┊           ║ 0           ║ 
║ Microsoft Print to PDF             ┊           ║ 0x76213A00  ║
║ OneNote for Windows 10             ┊           ║ 0x162149B2  ║
║ Brother MFC-7840W Printer          ┊           ║ 0xF62139F2  ║
║ Microsoft XPS Document Writer      ┊           ║ 0x6B214609  ║
║ EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)┊           ║ 0           ║ 
║ Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)          ║ 0           ║ 
║ OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)          ║ 0           ║
║ Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)         ║ 0           ║
║ Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)   ║ 0           ║ 
║ Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)   ║ 0           ║ 
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
                                     ┊
```

## Research Effort

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says that if you want to get a printer device context you must pass **`WINSPOOL`** as the *driver*:

> ### How To: Retrieve a Printer Device Context
>
> To render to a specific printer, you must specify "WINSPOOL" as the device and pass the correct name of the printer to [**CreateDC**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490(v=vs.85).aspx). You can also pass a [**DEVMODE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) structure in the call to **CreateDC** if you want to provide device-specific initialization data for the device driver when you create the device context.
>
> The following example shows a call to [**CreateDC**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490(v=vs.85).aspx) in which the "WINSPOOL" driver is selected and the printer name is specified by name.
> C++
>
> ```
> printerDC = CreateDC( L"WINSPOOL", printerName, NULL, NULL);
> ```

But MSDN also [recommends that you pass `NULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdca) for printer devices:

> `pwszDriver`
>
> A pointer to a null-terminated character string that specifies either DISPLAY or the name of a specific display device. For printing, we recommend that you pass **NULL** to *lpszDriver* because GDI ignores *lpszDriver* for printer devices.

I mention it, because there is a lot of code out there that passes:

- empty string
- null
- the name of the device
- the name of the driver
- the literal `winspool`
- the literal `WINSPOOL`

## CRME

Here are the Complete Reproduciable Minimal Example for every possible combination of arguments i can think of:

1. **Passing recommended `NULL` as the driver:**

   ```
   // MSDN: "For printing, we recommend that you pass NULL to lpszDriver because GDI ignores lpszDriver for printer devices."
   // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdca
   CreateDC(nil,        'Xerox Phaser 6500N',                           nil, nil) ==> 0x85214A3E
   CreateDC(nil,        'Send To OneNote 2010',                         nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC(nil,        'OneNote for Windows 10',                       nil, nil) ==> 0x162149B2
   CreateDC(nil,        'Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)',       nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC(nil,        'OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC(nil,        'Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)', nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC(nil,        'Microsoft XPS Document Writer',                nil, nil) ==> 0x6B214609
   CreateDC(nil,        'Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC(nil,        'Microsoft Print to PDF',                       nil, nil) ==> 0x76213A00
   CreateDC(nil,        'Fax (redirected 2)',                           nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC(nil,        'Fax',                                          nil, nil) ==> 0xBF21704F
   CreateDC(nil,        'EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)',          nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC(nil,        'Brother MFC-7840W Printer',                    nil, nil) ==> 0xF62139F2
   ```
2. **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [and some other people](http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/2008-12/00064/Re-CreateDC()-problem-with-printer-drivers-on-Windows-Server-200x.html) have said pass `WINSPOOL` as the Driver Name:**

   ```
   // Another MSDN page says use "WINSPOOL"
   // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Xerox Phaser 6500N',                           nil, nil) ==> 0x29214466
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Send To OneNote 2010',                         nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'OneNote for Windows 10',                       nil, nil) ==> 0x0C2140A2
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)',       nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)', nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer',                nil, nil) ==> 0xB52134E4
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Microsoft Print to PDF',                       nil, nil) ==> 0x8B213BA3
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Fax (redirected 2)',                           nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Fax',                                          nil, nil) ==> 0xD62137F0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)',          nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'Brother MFC-7840W Printer',                    nil, nil) ==> 0x3D2132F3
   ```
3. **Try passing an empty string.**

   ```
   // Try empty string as the driver :shrug:
   CreateDC('',         'Xerox Phaser 6500N',                           nil, nil) ==> 0x15213FFF
   CreateDC('',         'Send To OneNote 2010',                         nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('',         'OneNote for Windows 10',                       nil, nil) ==> 0x28212DA3
   CreateDC('',         'Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)',       nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('',         'OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('',         'Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)', nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('',         'Microsoft XPS Document Writer',                nil, nil) ==> 0xAD212B04
   CreateDC('',         'Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('',         'Microsoft Print to PDF',                       nil, nil) ==> 0x17211B7E
   CreateDC('',         'Fax (redirected 2)',                           nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('',         'Fax',                                          nil, nil) ==> 0xE72129DE
   CreateDC('',         'EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)',          nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('',         'Brother MFC-7840W Printer',                    nil, nil) ==> 0x8B212758
   ```
4. **[Some people](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/764057/GDI-Drawing-and-Printing) have [suggested duplicating](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/764057/GDI-Drawing-and-Printing) the *device* name into the *driver* name:**

   ```
   CreateDC('Xerox Phaser 6500N',                              'Xerox Phaser 6500N',                           nil, nil) ==> 0x67211FDA
   CreateDC('Send To OneNote 2010',                            'Send To OneNote 2010',                         nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('OneNote for Windows 10',                          'OneNote for Windows 10',                       nil, nil) ==> 0xD52160FA
   CreateDC('Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)',          'Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)',       nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)',           'OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)',    'Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)', nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('Microsoft XPS Document Writer',                   'Microsoft XPS Document Writer',                nil, nil) ==> 0xBE211038
   CreateDC('Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)',           'Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)',        nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('Microsoft Print to PDF',                          'Microsoft Print to PDF',                       nil, nil) ==> 0xC0211291
   CreateDC('Fax (redirected 2)',                              'Fax (redirected 2)',                           nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('Fax',                                             'Fax',                                          nil, nil) ==> 0xBF2176BF
   CreateDC('EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)',             'EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)',          nil, nil) ==> 0
   CreateDC('Brother MFC-7840W Printer',                       'Brother MFC-7840W Printer',                    nil, nil) ==> 0
   ```

### CreateIC also fails

`CreateIC` is just a *"lightweight"* form of `CreateDC` (you can use it to get information about a device, but you can't draw GDI with it). It also means that `CreateIC` also fails on Windows 10.

## Bonus Reading

- [QC127390: Operation not supported on selected printer](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=127390)
- [Random "Printer selected is not valid" errors on Win2K8R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137253/random-printer-selected-is-not-valid-errors-on-win2k8r2)
- [MSDN Forums: XPS and StartDoc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/764057/GDI-Drawing-and-Printing)
- [GDI Drawing and Printing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/764057/GDI-Drawing-and-Printing)
- [CreateDC() problem with printer drivers on Windows Server 200x](http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/2008-12/00064/Re-CreateDC()-problem-with-printer-drivers-on-Windows-Server-200x.html)
- [Printing from a Windows Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/06/24/printing-from-a-windows-service.aspx)
- [MSDN: How To: Retrieve a Printer Device Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Printer CreateDC/CreateIC fails on Windows 10 with redirected printers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78102104)
- [Printer CreateDC/CreateID fails on Windows 10 with a redirected RDP printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093812)

**Note**: I have repurposed this old unrelated question of mine to ask this new question here see here before you. If the question here gets an answer, i'll copy it to the question's permanent home, and revert this question back to the unrelated question it started as.

## Printer Name Length

@TylerH had a good insight, possible issue with printer name length:

It's **possible**. If i sort the printer names by length, you can see it nearly works; except for one that makes that theory breakdown:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Printer name (sorted by name length)           ║ Returned DC ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Fax                                ┊           ║ 0xBF21704F  ║
║ Fax (redirected 2)                 ┊           ║ 0           ║ 
║ Xerox Phaser 6500N                 ┊           ║ 0x85214A3E  ║
║ Send To OneNote 2010               ┊           ║ 0           ║ 
║ Microsoft Print to PDF             ┊           ║ 0x76213A00  ║
║ OneNote for Windows 10             ┊           ║ 0x162149B2  ║
║ Brother MFC-7840W Printer          ┊           ║ 0xF62139F2  ║
║ Microsoft XPS Document Writer      ┊           ║ 0x6B214609  ║
║ EPSON ET-2800 Series (redirected 2)┊           ║ 0           ║ 
║ Microsoft Print to PDF (redirected 2)          ║ 0           ║ 
║ OneNote for Windows 10 (redirected 2)          ║ 0           ║
║ Colson on shielddesktop (redirected 2)         ║ 0           ║
║ Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)   ║ 0           ║ 
║ Microsoft XPS Document Writer (redirected 2)   ║ 0           ║ 
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I think this is *correlation* implying causation: remote printer names are longer because of the  `(redirected 2)` suffix.

It also cannot be the cause, because in that linked question, the issue is with filling the `DEVMODE` structure; which we are not (and do not need) to do.

Thirdly, a *redirected* printer with a name shorter than 35 characters still fails.

And finally the linked post was about the user trying to *retrieve* the name of the printer, and finding that [`DEVMODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea) truncates the name to 35 characters:

> Note that this name may be truncated to fit in the `dmDeviceName` array.

so the other questioner is not getting the entire name he wants. When he specifies the *"full"* printer name, it works.

So, no; not a related problem.

Comment: The `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED` may not be accurate, as the documentation (as you state) only reports that the function returns NULL on failure. However, it may well be that the XPS document writer does not support returning an information context on Win10.. Did you try setting your HP printer as the default (or setting it as the active printer with `PrinterIndex`) to see if that also fails?

Comment: FWIW this seems like a pure winapi question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought about that but a) i didn't want to scare off people with talk of VCL framework code (i.e. not my code) and b) i wanted to pre-empt anyone who might ask [*why are you doing that?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6411318/12597), and i would have no idea how to answer them - since i wasn't the one doing it!

Comment: I suspect though, that the winapi experts may steer clear of a Delphi question

Comment: If you use [`EnumPrinters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do you get the name you expect for the printer? (Use [`Level 2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the printer name and driver name)

Comment: @theB Yes. It returns `HP DeskJet 930C/932C/935C`/`HP DeskJet 930C/932C/935C` and `Microsoft XPS Document Writer v4`/`Microsoft XPS Document Writer`. Both of which i've now tried.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It must be a bug in the Delphi compiler, or XE6 Winapi translations. There's no way `CreateDC('WINSPOOL', 'HP DeskJet 930C/932C/935C', nil, nil);` can fail in Windows 10 and nobody noticed before now. Notepad prints. It *has* to be Delphi :(

Comment: You confirmed that I presume, with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Even more inscideous than that. It worked when i called CreateDCA from Delphi 7. Then i returned to XE6 and it was fixed... As though the entire print subsystem got into an invalid state. I'm going to reboot shortly and see if the failure returns.

Comment: Sounds like it could be environmental

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wonder if its similar to the common bug in the VCL (QC107919) where a `devmode` structure contains invalid garbage. The VCL code is already wrong in other ways (containing Win16 legacy code). Its random whether it will happen in the launched process; meanwhile other applications can print. It's going to be an impossible to solve Delphi-on-Windows-10 bug. Possibly related to unaligned structures, random garbage that just happens to tickle the driver the wrong way, ASLR, DEP... that only me and my customers find on Windows 10.

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap the desired functionality into a native DLL (written by you in C++) and call _that_ from the Delphi code? It's more of a workaround, but it would at least identify whether the issue is in the built-in library or on the Windows side of the call. _(Note that I'm not a Delphi programmer, so feel free to ignore this if it's fundamentally impossible)_

Comment: Stopping and restarting the **Print Spooler** (`Spooler`) service also does not fix it.

Comment: @SimonMourier *"FWIW I've been testing a `auto hdc = CreateDC(nullptr, L"Microsoft Print To PDF (redirected 1)", nullptr, nullptr);` in a Windows 10 box connected using Remote Desktop and it works fine (the non redirected text works fine too)"* Would that happen to have been a 64-bit  process, or a 32-bit process?